# An unused Value that is never used, but Is, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Still learning React, and I see a warning pop up saying "data" is assigned a value but never used, but is used not much later. I think unfortunately it is causing problems later on down my code and seems to have snowballed, so I'm trying to get to the root. Here's the code:

```js
export const deleteProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_REQUEST, payload: productId });
  const {
    userSignin: { userInfo },
  } = getState();
  try {
    const { data } = Axios.delete(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
    });
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL, error: message });
  }
};
```

Comment: `Axios.delete` is not being "awaited".

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried that as well, and is still registering.

        const { data } = await Axios.delete(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
Is still causing problems.

Comment: In this code, `data` isn't used. Do you not want to use it? Please make sure your example is a [mcve].

Comment: Apologies, still learning React, I'm just trying to get rid of the warning and I'm curious as to what I can change to get rid of it. I should've clarified. The code still runs, I just want to get rid of the warning. Deleting { data } did not work.

Comment: If you are not using `data` try replacing `const { data } = Axios` with `await Axios`. --- please note that this is not a react issue.

Comment: Maybe you mix it up... With const { data } you destructuring "Axios" to a value called "data" and this is not used i this part of your code. Maybe you mean error.response.data is the same... But is not. This "data" refers to "error.response".

Comment: @evolutionxbox That was it! Ran the code and it worked, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` variable on line 7:

```js
const { data } = Axios.delete(`/api/products/${productId}`
```

It is never used. Later you access the `data` property in the `response` object, in line 13 and 14, and it has nothing to do with the actual `data` variable on line 7. It is just a property with key `data` that stores some value inside the `response` object.